# DLL's "Not Found" Despite being in the same folder

Tags: wine

Here is the what is some of what returning after attempting to run the exe.

```
04c4:err:environ:init_peb starting L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\maillist.exe" in experimental wow64 mode
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\polspell.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library polspell.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\Numbers.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library Numbers.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library AFC100.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\PRTRED.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\polspell.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library polspell.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\Numbers.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library Numbers.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library AFC100.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\DOCRED.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\polspell.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library polspell.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\Numbers.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library Numbers.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library AFC100.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\THOMA.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\polspell.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library polspell.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\Numbers.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library Numbers.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library AFC100.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\IO.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\polspell.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library polspell.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\Numbers.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library Numbers.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library LayoutManager_1_2_0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library AFC100.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\DM.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\polspell.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library polspell.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\Numbers.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library Numbers.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\AFC100.dll") not found
(x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\Bulkmail.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\BCGCBPRO800.dll") not found
04c4:err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPRO800.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\maillist.exe") not found
04c4:err:module:loader_init Importing dlls for L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySoftware\\AddressBook\\maillist.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Comment: Try again with `wine32` instead? Running 32-bit PEs (EXEs) on a 64-bit Wine is on the bleeding edge, and many programs working fine under 32-bit Wine won't just work with 64-bit Wine.